# Differences between StringGetAsync vs StringGet in StackExchange.Redis Multiplexer Connection

Tags: async-await, redis, stackexchange.redis

I was wondering that there are any performance differences between
`StringGetAsync` vs `StringGet` while we are using the **StackExchange.Redis Multiplexer Connection**.

The [StackExhange.Redis Document](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers.html) explained like

> When used concurrently by different callers, it automatically pipelines the separate requests, so regardless of whether the requests use blocking or asynchronous access, the work is all pipelined.

The explanation is really confusing. Which one provides more performing code?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            taskList.Add(Task.Run( async () =>
            {
                var value =  db.StringGetAsync("Localization:ECommerceBackend:tr-TR:bo_IsThereAnyStoreStock");
            }));
        }
```

or

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            taskList.Add(Task.Run( async () =>
            {
                var value =  db.StringGet("Localization:ECommerceBackend:tr-TR:bo_IsThereAnyStoreStock");
            }));
        }
```